# XML com Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

Eu estou nos últimos dias buscando no Google algo que sirva para ler um arquivo XML simples e exibir em uma pagina HTML usando javascript puro, não quero usar Jquery, apenas javascript.

Eu gostaria que os dados do XML sejam exibidos em uma tabela comum HTML com TR e TD.

Tem algum jeito simples de se fazer isso ? Ou algum exemplo online para testar ? Pois eu não achei.

Obrigado

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_intro.asp

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_applications.asp

Comment: acredito que possa te ajudar https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML

Comment: Eu consegui rodar os exemplos no firefox, mas eu preciso rodar localmente fora de um servidor, mas o Google Chrome esta me dando esse erro                                                                                        ( Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource. ).

Comment: Tem como liberar pelo codigo javascript ?

Comment: @abduzeedo, por questões de segurança, você não pode fazer uma requisição AJAX para outro servidor, a menos que o mesmo declare de forma explicita que aceita este tipo de requisição. em toda via, você pode fazer uso de um CORS Proxy, como por exemplo o `https://crossorigin.me`.

Comment: Então, os computadores que rodarão isso não possuem internet e não posso instalar servidor web nesses computadores por questões de segurança, qual a melhor forma de se fazer um leitor XML com javascript e que eu consiga usar em qualquer computador localmente ? O arquivo XML esta na mesma pasta do arquivo HTML.

Comment: @abduzeedo atualizei a resposta, ao utilizar a FileAPI você poderá ler um XML da maquina do Usuario.

Comment: Obrigado amigo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

você pode fazer uma requisição `AJAX` para ler o `XML`, uma vez que o mesmo seja carregado, você pode navegar pelo mesmo de forma semelhante ao que você navega pelos elementos `DOM` da sua pagina, usando `getElementById`, `getElementsByTagName`, etc.

abaixo segue um exemplo de como ler um XML com alguns livros, uma vez que

```js
// copiando os dados da tag `book` para o objeto `Book`
var Book = function (node) {
  var that = this;
  this.id = node.id;      
  [].forEach.call(node.childNodes, function (child, indice) {
    if (child.nodeType == 1) {
      that[child.nodeName] = child.textContent;
    }
  });
}

// criando um link para um XML. 
var xml = document.getElementById("xml").innerHTML;
var url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([xml], { type: "application/xml" }));
var tbody = document.querySelector("tbody");

// lendo um XML por AJAX.
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.open("GET", url, true)
httpRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
    var catalog = httpRequest.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("catalog")[0];
    var books = catalog.getElementsByTagName("book");
    [].forEach.call(books, function (node, indice) {
      var book = new Book(node);     
      var linha = document.createElement("tr");      
      for (var indice = 0; indice < 6; indice++) {
        var celula = document.createElement("td");
        linha.appendChild(celula);
      }
      
      linha.dataset.id = book.id;
      linha.children[0].textContent = book.author;
      linha.children[1].textContent = book.title;
      linha.children[2].textContent = book.genre;
      linha.children[3].textContent = book.price;
      linha.children[4].textContent = book.publish_date;
      linha.children[5].textContent = book.description;
      
      tbody.appendChild(linha);
    });
  }
});
httpRequest.send();
```

```css
tr td {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

tr td:nthchild(5) {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Author</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Genre</th>
      <th>Prince</th>
      <th>Publish Date</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table> 
<template id="xml">
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <catalog>
    <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
        with XML.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
        an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
        of the world.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk103">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
        society in England, the young survivors lay the 
        foundation for a new society.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk104">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
      <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
        agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
        for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
        Ascendant.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk105">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date>
      <description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, 
        battle one another for control of England. Sequel to 
        Oberon's Legacy.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk106">
      <author>Randall, Cynthia</author>
      <title>Lover Birds</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-09-02</publish_date>
      <description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology 
        conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk107">
      <author>Thurman, Paula</author>
      <title>Splish Splash</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>A deep sea diver finds true love twenty 
        thousand leagues beneath the sea.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk108">
      <author>Knorr, Stefan</author>
      <title>Creepy Crawlies</title>
      <genre>Horror</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-06</publish_date>
      <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches,
        centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk109">
      <author>Kress, Peter</author>
      <title>Paradox Lost</title>
      <genre>Science Fiction</genre>
      <price>6.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>After an inadvertant trip through a Heisenberg
        Uncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems 
        of being quantum.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk110">
      <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
      <title>Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>36.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-09</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in 
        detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk111">
      <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
      <title>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>36.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-01</publish_date>
      <description>The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in 
        detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing, 
        SAX and more.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk112">
      <author>Galos, Mike</author>
      <title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>49.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
        looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
        integrated into a comprehensive development 
        environment.</description>
    </book>
  </catalog>
</template>
```

No exemplo acima utilizei um blob para criar um link para um XML em memoria, em um sistema final, isto não é necessario, afinal você já deve ter o XML hospedado na sua Maquina.

Em todo caso, esta abordagem pode ser util, caso precise ler um XML hospedado na maquina do Usuario, para tal o usuario irá precisar fazer o upload do arquivo, então você poderá ler o mesmo.

```js
// copiando os dados da tag `book` para o objeto `Book`
var Book = function (node) {
  var that = this;
  this.id = node.id;      
  [].forEach.call(node.childNodes, function (child, indice) {
    if (child.nodeType == 1) {
      that[child.nodeName] = child.textContent;
    }
  });
}

// criando um link para um XML. 
var tbody = document.querySelector("tbody");
var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload");

fileUpload.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
  var file = fileUpload.files[0];
  if (file.type.indexOf("xml") == -1)
    return;

  var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  httpRequest.open("GET", url, true)
  httpRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
      var catalog = httpRequest.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("catalog")[0];
      var books = catalog.getElementsByTagName("book");
      [].forEach.call(books, function (node, indice) {
        var book = new Book(node);     
        var linha = document.createElement("tr");      
        for (var indice = 0; indice < 6; indice++) {
          var celula = document.createElement("td");
          linha.appendChild(celula);
        }

        linha.dataset.id = book.id;
        linha.children[0].textContent = book.author;
        linha.children[1].textContent = book.title;
        linha.children[2].textContent = book.genre;
        linha.children[3].textContent = book.price;
        linha.children[4].textContent = book.publish_date;
        linha.children[5].textContent = book.description;

        tbody.appendChild(linha);
      });
    }
  });
  httpRequest.send();
});
```

```css
tr td {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

tr td:nthchild(5) {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<input id="fileUpload" type="file" />
<table>  
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Author</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Genre</th>
      <th>Prince</th>
      <th>Publish Date</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Uma forma mais simples de obter o mesmo resultado, é utilizar um `FileReader` no lugar de combinar o `URL.createObjectURL(file)` com `XMLHttpRequest`, mas ao utilizar o `XMLHttpRequest`, você pode usar a mesma base de codigo, para ler arquivos `*.xml` locais e remotos. Em todo caso segue um exemplo usando o `FileReader`.

```
var file = fileUpload.files[0];
var leitor = new FileReader();
leitor.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var xmlDocument = new DOMParser().parseFromString(this.result, "text/xml");
  var catalog = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("catalog")[0];
  //restante do codigo aqui.
});
reader.readAsText(file );
```